# Scroll along 1 axis at time using 2 finger scrolling

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I use 2 finger scrolling intensively and have discovered an annoying feature in Ubuntu (I use 14.04): when I scroll vertically the horizontal scrolling is also enabled, which is what I absolutely don't want to happen.

I have found a bug report about it, but it was reported in 2011 and it seems, that nothing new happened since then:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43385

I also checked the synaptics driver manpage, but haven't found any solution for this:
http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html

Does anybody know, how it can be fixed?